# Video preview not working using MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android

We are trying to record video using MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE in one of our applications.
The file needs to be saved in internal storage and we are granting permission runtime.

The issue is the video is getting recorded and saved in the provided uri but in few devices when tried to play the preview it says video cannot be played but the video is actually recorded in the path.

Below is my code.

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)

{
    //  Let's get rid of the my-moments screen because it will free up some memory for post capture screen
    String videoPath = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".mp4";
    File videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/media", videoPath);
    try {
        videoFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri providerUri = FileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath("media/" + videoPath).build();
    mCurrentCameraUri = Uri.fromFile(videoFile);
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, providerUri);
    takeVideoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(takeVideoIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        MainActivity.this.grantUriPermission(packageName, providerUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
}
```

The manifest fileprovider code is

```
<provider
    android:name=".adapters.contentprovider.FileContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"
    android:exported="true"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.example.FileContentProvider.STREAM_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>
```

The xml path is

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="media" path=""/>
</paths>
```

Could anyone please suggest what is going wrong in this devices.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem? I'm currently encountering the same issue; video is recorded and saved, can be viewed outside of the preview but preview always says it cannot be played.